# How do you make a material that rotates around a focal point, like a pie chart?

Tags: texturing, materials, uv, texture-painting, texture-baking

I'm ultimately trying to make a material that emulates how a fan looks. I know how to make a wave texture, and a circular wave texture, but neither of those have all the waves come to a focal point in the center. Basically a wave texture for a fan so I don't need to create the geometry of the fan blades.

The AC unit in my pic models every single blade, and while that looks cool, it's not performant for my purposes. I just want a material that does a good enough job of emulating how that looks. Also does someone have a better way for me to describe what I'm looking for than "pie chart esque wave texture"?

[image: example]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this node setup. You can write *#frame* in the Value node field to make it keep up with the current frame (when animating):

[image: Fan]

That's just the basics of the "waves" converging at the center and rotating. To make it more convincing, change the Wave Texture type to "Saw", change the ColorRamp interpolation back to "Linear" and use it as the basis for a Bump map as well as the Color:

[image: Fan2]

If you want to get even more realistic, use the ColoRamp as the basis for an alpha. I set the second ColorRamp to "constant" to make sure it has a good cutoff before connecting as alpha. I also used a second ColorRamp for the basecolor just to give an extra edge of darkness on the blades to help with the sense of depth. Remember, if you're using EEVEE, change the materials *Blend Mode* to *Alpha-Blend*:

[image: Fan3]

Looks like this (note - I changed the frame multiplication factor to 0.02 in this example to make it slower for the gif. Also, the apparent "speed jumps" in the example are because I had to cut off the recording at a random frame to make the gif small enough):

[image: Fan]

Comment: Very much like this one.. going the extra mile :)

Comment: This is amazing! Thank you! What is the reason for connecting the WaveTexture to ColorRamp node through the Fac and not the Color? It seems to produce the same result

Comment: Yeah, usually it is the same, but the difference between Color and Fac is that Color gives a 3 value output (can be used a vector sometimes) and Fac gives a single float. Since I only needed the float value, I used Fac.